# drupal 7 db_select with OR statement

Tags: database, drupal-7

I am trying to execute the following code:

```
            $state  =   db_select('webform_email_confirm', 'wec')
            ->fields('wec')
            ->condition('nid', $form['nid']['#value'], '=')
            ->condition('cid1', $form['cid']['#value'], '=')
            ->or('cid2', $form['cid']['#value'], '=')
            ->execute()
            ->fetchAssoc();
```

The third statement, `->or('cid2', $form['cid']['#value'], '=')`, does not work.

I need to match records in my database in either **cid1** or **cid2**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to use the db_or(), or the $query->where constructs.

Please have a look at [this page](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_or/7) for more information.

So basically, try:

```
$or = db_or()
         ->condition('cid1', $form['cid']['#value'])
         ->condition('cid2',  $form['cid']['#value']);

$state  = db_select('webform_email_confirm', 'wec')
        ->fields('wec')
        ->condition('nid', $form['nid']['#value'], '=')
        ->condition($or)
        ->execute()
        ->fetchAssoc();
```

The [examples on the drupal website](http://drupal.org/node/310086) may be useful too:

```
$query
  ->condition('field1', array(1, 2), 'IN')
  ->condition(db_or()->condition('field2', 5)->condition('field3', 6))
// Results in:
// (field1 IN (:db_placeholder_1, :db_placeholder_2) AND (field2 = :db_placeholder3 OR field3 = :db_placeholder_4))
```

Comment: Thank you. I saw that earlier but wasn't paying enough attention

Comment: Good luck! Drupal can be confusing at times, but I kind of like it!